# Grails fixtures

Tags: grails, fixtures

I was trying to use fixtures plugin for initial (seed)data loading.. the documentation seems very short.. can anyone give some details about
  1. where to define all the data, and in which order
2. how to give complex data type (joda time, currency etc)
3. how to load the fixure data only once for the initial data

thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Grails Fixtures plugin documentation is now quite ok, check it [here](http://gpc.github.io/grails-fixtures/)

After installing the plugin you will have a new folder in your Grails App directory called "fixtures". There you may store *.groovy files with the given test data written in the documented DSL.

Example init.groovy file:

```
// Import needed classes
// Defining some initial testdata
fixture {
    cat0(Category, name: "My category 1")
    cat1(Category, name: "My category 2")
}
```

The fixture definitions have to be in the fixture closure.

---

### Edit

Even though the original link to the documentation is not online anymore, the content can still be found [in its repository](https://github.com/gpc/fixtures/tree/master/src/docs/guide).

Comment: I know this post is older, but it looks like the documentation link is dead now and I can't google if it moved somewhere else - does anyone have an up-to-date one?